# Do the continuity axiom and transitivity axiom justify non-satiation?

Tags: microeconomics, preferences

Let's assume on the contrary that the indifference curve is "thick" or crosses. We can only assume the four axioms: completeness, transitivity, reflexivity and continuity. We do not assume strict monotonicity of preferences.

Define the IC as $\{y \in X: y \sim x\}$ where $X$ is a (possibly non-finite) set of consumption bundle and $x$ is arbitrarily chosen from $X$.

I do not see a way to prove this without assuming monotonicity at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A counterexample**

Suppose the preference relation $\preceq$ is such that for all bundles $x,y$ we have $x \sim y$. This relation satisfies transitivity and continuity (it satisfies all four "axioms") but does not satisfy non-satiation.

Comment: Could you please re-explain this? I don't understand. Are we considering a set of indifferent bundles?

Comment: We are considering the preference relation which is indifferent between all bundles.

Comment: Yes, I meant that- the consumer is indifferent between the bundles. Thanks for clarifying!